# kie-server-showcase /kie-server is forbidden

Tags: drools, kie

The latest **7.42.0.Final** kie-server or kie-server-showcase container is working and deployed but context path /kie-server is forbidden. But, the rest service is working fine. Any reason?

I followed the document mentioned in this repo
https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/kie-server-showcase/

Answer (score 0):

You can look into web.xml here: https://github.com/kiegroup/droolsjbpm-integration/blob/master/kie-server-parent/kie-server-wars/kie-server/src/main/webc-resources/WEB-INF/web.xml

Except some urls, all of them need kie-server and user roles for authorization.

Best regards,

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)